# How to find missing values in a sequence with PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm, find

Suppose you have an array "value => timestamp". The values are increasing with the time but they can be reset at any moment.

For example :

```
$array = array(
1 => 6000,
2 => 7000,
3 => 8000,
7 => 9000,
8 => 10000,
9 => 11000,
55 => 1000,
56 => 2000,
57 => 3000,
59 => 4000,
60 => 5000,
);
```

I would like to retrieve all the missing values from this array.

This example would return :

```
array(4,5,6,58)
```

I don't want all the values between 9 and 55 because 9 is newer than the other higher values.

In real condition the script will deal with thousands of values so it need to be efficient.

Thanks for your help!

---

UPDATE :
The initial array can be ordered by timestamps if it is easier for the algorithm.

---

UPDATE 2 :
In my example the values are UNIX timestamps so they would look more like this : 1285242603 but for readability reason I simplified it.

Comment: That's very easy to do... did you try? If so, where did you fail?

Comment: What about 10, 11, …, 53, 54?

Comment: You need iterate over it and apply your conditions as you get to each element. Seems a strange requirement.

Comment: If you can please tell more about why you will require this type of functionality, then it will help the others guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s another solution:

```
$prev = null;
$missing = array();
foreach ($array as $curr => $value) {
    if (!is_null($prev)) {
        if ($curr > $prev+1 && $value > $array[$prev]) {
            $missing = array_merge($missing, range($prev+1, $curr-1));
        }
    }
    $prev = $curr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

- Keep comparing adjacent array keys. If
  they are consecutive you do nothing.
- If they are not consecutive then you
  check their values, if the value has
  dropped from a higher value to a
  lower value, it means there was a
  reset so you do nothing.
- If the value has not dropped then it
  is a case of missing key(s). All the
  numbers between the two keys(extremes
  not included) are part of the result.

Translated in code:

```
$array = array( 1 => 6000, 2 => 7000, 3 => 8000, 7 => 9000, 8 => 10000, 
                9 => 11000,55 => 1000, 56 => 2000, 57 => 3000, 59 => 4000, 
                60 => 5000,);

$keys = array_keys($array);
for($i=0;$i<count($array)-1;$i++) {
  if($array[$keys[$i]] < $array[$keys[$i+1]] && ($keys[$i+1]-$keys[$i] != 1) ) {
           print(implode(' ',range($keys[$i]+1,$keys[$i+1]-1)));
           print "\n";
   }   
}
```

[Working link](http://www.ideone.com/8D61R)

Comment: Thanks for ideone.com , I didn't know this website!

Answer (score 1):

This gives the desired result `array(4,5,6,58)`:

```
$previous_value = NULL;
$temp_store = array();
$missing = array();
$keys = array_keys($array);

for($i = min($keys); $i <= max($keys); $i++)
{
    if(!array_key_exists($i, $array))
    {
        $temp_store[] = $i;
    }
    else
    {
        if($previous_value < $array[$i])
        {
            $missing = array_merge($missing, $temp_store);
        }
        $temp_store = array();
        $previous_value = $array[$i];
    }
}

var_dump($missing);
```

Or just use Gumbo's very smart solution ;-)

Comment: This solution seems slow if the gap between the min and the max is very large. This could happen in my case. But Thanks!!