# Comparing Incrementing Series Values With PHP

Tags: php, mysql, comparison

I have a series of numbers that always increment logically.  these numbers are actually representations of version numbers in a database.  So for example, here si some sample data:

- 1.0
- 1.0.1
- 2.0.0
- 2.0.1

Using PHP, I know I can compare the values and determine that 2.0.1 is less than 2.0.3, for example, but is there of way of pr grammatically determining that jumping from 2.0.1 to 2.0.3 breaks the series (skips 2.0.2)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find missing values in a sequence with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777817/how-to-find-missing-values-in-a-sequence-with-php)

Comment: I beg to disagree the duplicate: Question 3777817 talks about integers, but in this the extraction of comparable items is the main point.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Be carefull! A simple PHP string comparison of `1.0.1` against `1.0.2`, `1.1.0` or `2.0` will work as expected, but in string comparison

```
'1.10.1' < '1.9.9'
'10.0' < '2.0'
```

Which I suspect is not what you want. In short: Things break, when digit counts change.

So you will need to abstract away the comparison by pulling the real integers out of your version string, this makes it trivial to not only implement a `compare()` function, but to also implement something like a `is_sequence()` to check for holes.

Comment: To make it clear: 1.) Creating `compare()` will help against spurious string compares - this was not the question. 2.) Creating `is_sequence()` is my answer to the question, and it is heavily inspired by 1.)

Comment: To make it even clearer: He has to *pull[ing] the real integers out of your version string*, then solve the problem of `is_sequence()` for integers. This is left as an exercise for the reader.